# Border-radius not applying to image

Tags: html, css

For the purpose of adding a button later, I have placed my images inside of their own individual div. After this, I tried to reapply the border radius that was working previously and it is not applying to the image. However when I use it on an item not in a div it works fine.

```
.image1 {
  padding:0 13px 0 0;
  float: left;
  width: 220px;
  border-radius: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Try `overflow: hidden;`. I thought that wasn't necessary anymore, but maybe it is.

Comment: can you create a fiddle to show the problem with the html

Comment: Worked, thanks very much! Out of curiosity why is that necessary only inside of a div?

Comment: @dippas, questioner asked about `<div class="image1"><img ...></div>`. In that case, the image really overflows the div: http://jsfiddle.net/azjku939/

Answer (score 2):

You should add `overflow: hidden;` container div's css. Because you're applying `border-radius` on a div. border-radius not for `<img>` tag according in your code. Also you have padding on container div. So you should be add `box-sizing: border-box;` to fix it. [Read more about box-sizing](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/azjku939/1/)

```
.image1 {
  padding:0 13px 0 0;
  float: left;
  width: 220px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  overflow:hidden;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: box-sizing:border-box; working perfectly!